# Changing width from RelativeLayout not affect children

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

**My code**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/leftSelectorView"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/grayBgLeft"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#bf484349" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/leftBorderView"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/boxLeft"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@mipmap/box_selector"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

i'm moving the `leftSelectorView` width ***`programmatically`***

```
leftSelectorView.getLayoutParams().width = 150;
```

and the `View` child is not affected.

> If i have a `child` inside `RelativeLayout` with `match_parent` in width and modify the width from `RelativeLayout`, how can update the width of `child`?

Using the `requestLayout` now update al childrens. (Thanks to ***@FunkTheMonk***)

> Now another problem has arisen with this. The RelativeLayout I'm trying to move, takes a few jumps as if sometimes take the new position and then the old position

My code:

```
leftBorderView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                detector.onTouchEvent(event);

                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {

                    int xMove = (int) event.getX();
                    Log.e("onTouch", "xMove===> " + xMove);

                    int widthMove = xMove < 50 ? 50 : 50 + xMove;

                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams parms = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(widthMove, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                    leftSelectorView.setLayoutParams(parms);
                    grayBgLeft.requestLayout();

                }

                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: I tried your code and its changing the child View's width to match the parent as well. Is this your complete code?

Comment: are you triggering layout after changing it? e.g. `leftSelectorView.requestLayout() `

Comment: @FunkTheMonk thanks man.. I had to give an id to View and use `requestLayout` to him. Now another problem has arisen with this.

The RelativeLayout I'm trying to move, takes a few jumps as if sometimes take the new position and then the old position